# Vaadin - securing Form Fields with ReadOnly good enough?

Tags: forms, security, binding, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I use Vaadin Flow and create some forms. Some of the fields should not become editable if the user does not have the "Admin" role.

Vaadin supports for this to set the form field like `TextField`to read-only or to disable the field completely. I also have seen that the `Binder` supports the `Binder.forField(...).bindReadOnly(...)`.

I am wondering which method I should use from a Security perspective because I noticed that in the Shadow root still a `<input>` field gets rendered which potentially can be "hacked".

So is Vaadin performing checks on the server side if a field is set to "read-only" but still gets transmitted? Or how has this scenario been secured in Vaadin?

```
EmailField email = new EmailField("Email");

Binder<User> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(User.class);
binder.setBean(user);

// some service to determine if Emailaddress can be edited for the current logged-in user 
boolean allowed = authorityService.isCurrentUserAdmin();

// 1. Method: set field to ReadOnly
email.setReadOnly(!allowed);

// OR

// 2. Method: set the binder to use only read-only getter
if(!allowed)
   binder.forField(email).bindReadOnly(User::getEmail);
```

For both cases still, an `<input>` field gets rendered. So is this secure enough in Vaadin or should I be worried and change the fields to use "SPAN" text Tags and special logic on the server side?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I bet you this borderlines a X-Y-problem.  The UI should not be your
"last line of defense" here. Is your `User` object some ORM object
with all the bells and whistles?  Then your problem lies there: those
kind of power must not be around your UI.  Create a layer for the
"verbs" (actions), that are allowed with your "subjects" (the objects)
and tighten that.

Editing user details allows showing the email, but does not allow to
edit it, then don't even allow that.  Make sure you are using
a guaranteed read-only-source (only add a getter (no setter) for the
email field; ideally make it final).  And for sending in the "change
user details request" into your layer, don't even accept the email
coming in.

This all said, the way vaadin deals with this: if the field is read
only, the value changes there will not go through.  A malicious client
setting the field back to write-able will not send it back (this is not
a classic HTTP-POST-form either, so that would be harder anyway).

But handling read-only for yourself *and* using a binder is a bad idea.
Because the binder at this point manages the read-only state.  So
messing with the field behind the back of the binder will result in
problems.

So the optimal approach is:

- make the field in the backing bean final
- only add a getter for the field
- use the binder to link the bean to the field; let the binder take care
  for dealing with read-only

Comment: Ok this would mean I need to create multiple DTO objects for my  persistent entity objects. One DTO for "Admin" role which has the setter methods and a Read-only DTO. Is this the usual pattern?

Comment: There are no silver bullets, but most non-trivial applications have
nearly none of the "stupid CRUD" (maybe there is some back-end where the
admin manages some drop-down-options).  The more clear-cut your borders
are, the less angle of attack there is.  Make sure a regular user _can
not_ write the email and whatever the UI does is just a nice feedback to
the user. And usually there is way more difference: users may only
change their own user; changing their email involves some opt-in-link
sent to them... while admins just could do whatever they fancy.